# HTML Table not working in Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a runtime HTML table and sending via mail. The table is added in the body of mail. But when the mail is triggered it is showing **System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable** instead of the contents of the table.

// .csPage:

```
HtmlTable tbl = new HtmlTable();
        tbl.Border = 1;
        tbl.CellSpacing = 0;
        HtmlTableRow trHeader = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableCell tcHeader = new HtmlTableCell();
        tcHeader.InnerText = "Mobile Number";
        HtmlTableCell tc1Header = new HtmlTableCell();
        tc1Header.InnerText = "Carrier";
        trHeader.Cells.Add(tcHeader);
        trHeader.Cells.Add(tc1Header);
        tbl.Rows.Add(trHeader);
 for (int i = 0; i < dvNumbers.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
                HtmlTableCell tc = new HtmlTableCell();
                tc.InnerText = dvNumbers.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                HtmlTableCell tc1 = new HtmlTableCell();
                tc1.InnerText = dvNumbers.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                tr.Cells.Add(tc1);
                tbl.Rows.Add(tr);

            }

            objMail.MobileDeactivationMail(txtMailTo.Text, txtMailCC.Text, txtMailBCC.Text, tbl);
```

// Mail Code:

```
public bool MobileDeactivationMail(string strReceiverMailId, string CC, string BCC, HtmlTable tbl)
    {
        bool blnIsMailSent = false;
        MailMessage objMailMsg;
        try
        {
            objMailMsg = new MailMessage();
            MailAddress FromAdd = new MailAddress("x@x.com");
            objMailMsg.From = FromAdd;
            objMailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(strReceiverMailId));
            if (CC != "")
                objMailMsg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(CC));
            if (BCC != "")
                objMailMsg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(BCC));
            objMailMsg.Subject = "Deactivation of Mobile Numbers";
            objMailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            objMailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            objMailMsg.Body = "<table style='font-family:Tahoma; font-size:small';><tr><td> Dear Sir/Mam</td<</tr>," + "<tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td><td><td>         Kindly Deactivate the following mobile numbers.</br></br>" + tbl + " </td></td></td></tr></table><table style='font-family:Tahoma; font-size:small';><tr><td>Regards,</td></tr><tr><td>HR</td></tr></table>";
            SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();
            SmtpMail.Port = 25;
            SmtpMail.Host = "xxxxx";
            System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx", "xxxxx");
            SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            SmtpMail.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
            SmtpMail.Send(objMailMsg);
            objMailMsg.Dispose();
            blnIsMailSent = true;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            blnIsMailSent = false;
        }

        return blnIsMailSent;
    }
```

Where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
objMailMsg.Body = "<table style='font-family:Tahoma; font-size:small';>
   <tr><td> Dear Sir/Mam</td<</tr>," + "<tr><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td><td><td>Kindly Deactivate the following mobile numbers.</br></br>" + tbl + " </td></td></td></tr></table>
   <table style='font-family:Tahoma; font-size:small';><tr><td>Regards,</td></tr><tr><td>HR</td>  </tr></table>";
```

Specificially:

```
" + tbl + "
```

As you are concatenating the object into your string, it will call `tbl.ToString()`

By default, this will return the class name - not the HTML of the table as you desire.

The way to solve this, using HTML table, is to write out the HTML directly. Unfortunately, InnerText and InnerHTML, although present, are not supported on this control ([MSDN HTMLTable Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable_properties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), so instead you have to use the RenderControl ([MSDN RenderControl documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htwek607%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) method:

```
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); 
        Html32TextWriter htmlWriter = new Html32TextWriter(writer); 
        tbl.RenderControl(htmlWriter); 
        string html = writer.ToString();
```

You can then concatenate this HTML string instead of `tbl`.

Comment: the document has `InnerText` and `InnerHtml` in the list

Comment: @RohitWagh From the documentation: "Gets or sets the content between the opening and closing tags of the control, without automatically converting special characters to their equivalent HTML entities. **This property is not supported for this control.** (Overrides HtmlContainerControl.InnerHtml.)" Furthermore, you'd want (if it existed!) the OuterHTML property anyway to get outer tags too, as, if it worked, InnerHTML would only give you everything *between* the Table tags.